# How to catch 404 errors using connect framework

Tags: node.js

How to catch 404 errors if we write a nodejs program that proxies to another location.

The code looks like this

```
 connect()
.use(couchForward(couch))
.listen(port);
```

The `couchForward` module forwards the request to another url specified in the `couch` object

```
module.exports = function(couch) {
    var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy(couch),
        couchTarget = couch.target;

    return function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('Received request: ' + req.url);

        req.headers['host'] = couchTarget.host + ':' + couchTarget.port;
        req.headers['authorization'] = couch.credentials;
        req.headers['x-forwarded-ssl'] = util.isSecureForwardedRequest(req);
        var forwardedFor = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
        req.headers['x-real-ip'] = forwardedFor
            ? forwardedFor.split(',',1)[0]
            : req.connection.remoteAddress;
        req.url = couch.path + req.url;

        console.log('Proxying to: ' + req.url);

        var startTime = new Date().getTime();

        proxy.proxyRequest(req, res);

        var endTime = new Date().getTime();

        var respTime = endTime - startTime;

        console.log('Response time for ' + req.url + ': ' + respTime + 'ms');

        next();

    }
}
```

I wrote

```
 connect()
.use(couchForward(couch))
.use(function(req,res){console.log("Broke!" + res.statusCode)})
.listen(port);
```

But the res.statusCode is always `200` for unknown reasons even if the target url does not exist

Comment: I would check the status returned with curl and if you still get 200 then the problem could be also server side.

Comment: No, the url returns 404. I am posting the couchForward module code in the original description

Comment: pls show code/link of the couchForward module, there should be the issue

Comment: @hereandnow78 I have updated the original description with the code for `couchForward` module

Comment: i saw it, what is httpProxy-Module?

Comment: I use this https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy module

Comment: according to [this example](http://nthloop.com/blog/local-dev-with-nodejs-proxy/) you dont need to use next inside your proxy-function. but otherwise i can't see what else could go wrong...