# Incorrect statusCode from http-proxy

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

This is a small proxy program I wrote to test some case.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    connect   = require('connect'),
    endpoint  = {
      host:   'googleeeeeee.com', // or IP address
      port:   80,
    },
    staticDir = 'public';

var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
var app = connect()
  .use(connect.logger('dev'))
  .use(function(req, res) {
      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, endpoint);
      console.log("Respose is " + res.statusCode);
  })
  .use(connect.static(staticDir))
  .listen(80);
  console.log("Server started");
```

this uses
    `"http-proxy": "0.8.x"`
    `"connect": "2.3.x"`

When I run this program and access it, the statusCode is 200 through the target URL does not exist. Any help much appreciated. This is in continuation with [How to catch 404 errors using connect framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725038/how-to-catch-404-errors-using-connect-framework)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by this code

Created a file called errorhandler.js

```
module.exports = function() {
        return function(req, res, next) {
                var end = res.end;
                res.end = function(chunk, encoding){
                        res.end = end;
                        res.end(chunk, encoding);
                        console.log("Reponse code is " + res.statusCode);

                };
                next();
        }
}
```

then included this in the middleware

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    connect   = require('connect'),
    endpoint  = {
      host:   'googleeeeeee.com', // or IP address
      port:   80,
    },
    staticDir = 'public';

var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
var app = connect()
  .use(require('./errorHandler').errorHandler())
  .use(connect.logger('dev'))
  .use(function(req, res) {
      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, endpoint);
  })
  .use(connect.static(staticDir))
  .listen(80);
  console.log("Server started");
```